# Possible Reverse Inheritance

Tags: inheritance

I would like to understand if class inheritance can be used to solve my problem.

Theoretically, I have two simple objects that have all the same abilities as each other but the syntax for accessing each ability is different from object to object.

I would like to have two classes that have all the same function but different syntax within the functions. This is of course, not a problem. I want the user to tell the app that he is using object A or B today and the app the chooses class A or B and then runs seamlessly.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example? This is a tad abstract.

Comment: If you have the same functionality but different syntax, you might want to use the `Adapter` pattern.

Comment: Daniel, I will look into the Adapter idea ... thank you. John, I have two databases with similar structures. One is for an android phone the other for a pc. The two classes are nearly identical but with different syntax. I would just like to know a simple way of making one object that can be used for either class, if there is such of course.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.